# How to analytically solve this integral?

Tags: integration

Consider the integral
$$
\frac{g}{(2\pi)^3} \int \frac{1}{1+
\exp\left({\frac{E(\vec{p}) - \mu}{T}}\right)}
d^{3}\vec{p},
$$
where
$$ E(\vec{p}) = \sqrt{|p|^{2}+m^{2}}.$$

I am unsure how to solve it when it is over a 3 dimensional vector. How can I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation. I suggest reformulating your question so that it refers to how to deal with generic integrals with respect to a vector.

Comment: Also, this question might be better suited for Math.SE

Comment: I doubt this can be solved analytically even in the 1-dimensional case (at least Mathematica fails to give an answer for this)

Answer (score 1):

No promises.

Step into spherical polar, for $\vec{p} = (p_x, p_y, p_z)$:

$$p_x = R\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\ p_y = R\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) \\ p_z = R\cos(\theta)$$
Where $R\in [0, +\infty) \quad \theta\in [0, \pi] \quad \phi\in [0, 2\pi]$.

Now I recognise a "physical notation" over there, that is $|p|^2$, which is usually ambiguous in physics. Do they mean simply $p_x^2 + p_y^2 + p_z^2$ or $(p_x^2 + p_y^2 + p_z^2)^2$?

Just asking because I have seen many of those, and many times both books and professors did strange things.

Assuming, anyway, the second hypothesis:

$$|p|^2 = (p_x^2 + p_y^2 + p_z^2)^2 = R^4$$

Now substituting into the integral, and arranging we arrive at

$$2\pi\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{R^2}{1 + \exp\left(\alpha + \beta\sqrt{R^4 + m^2}\right)}\ \text{d}R$$

where I left out the constants and $\alpha = -\frac{\mu}{T}$ and $\beta = \frac{1}{T}$

This integral is not resoluble in terms of elementary functions. If we make some hypotheses to smooth the integrand, we could get perhaps some asymptotic informations. To say, assuming $m$ is a small mass and $\mu$ is another small parameter, we can study the behaviour of

$$\sim \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{R^2}{1 + \exp\left(\beta R^2\right)}\ \text{d}R = \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(2 - \sqrt{2}\right)}{8 \beta^{3/2}}\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

if $\Re(\beta)> 0$

**Further extension**

We can actually give a close form in terms of poly-logarithm function when the term $\alpha$ is present:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{R^2}{1 + \exp\left(\alpha + \beta R^2\right)}\ \text{d}R = - \frac{\sqrt{\pi }\ \text{Li}_{\frac{3}{2}}\left(-e^{-\alpha}\right)}{4 \beta^{3/2}}$$

always for $\Re(\beta) > 0$.

**Going to add the second choice solution, that is the case in which $|p|^2 = R^2$.**

This is actually easier:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{R^2}{1 + \exp\left(\beta R\right)}\ \text{d}R = \frac{3}{2 \beta^3}\zeta (3) \quad\quad\quad \Re(\beta) > 0$$

Also, in the presence of $\alpha$:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{R^2}{1 + \exp\left(\alpha + \beta R^2\right)}\ \text{d}R = -\frac{2\ \text{Li}_3\left(-e^{-\alpha}\right)}{\beta^3}\quad\quad\quad \Re(\beta) > 0$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sqrt{R^2 + m^2}$  instead of  $\sqrt{R^4 + m^2}$ in the first integral?

Comment: @HansEngler That was indeed my doubt, for I have seen in the past the notation $|p|^2$ meant to be in both ways. Confusing and ambiguous. This is why I chose for the most likely form. Anyway, thank you for having reminded me that I need to add the second choice solution :D